# Best way to map elements of xml in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, exslt

I have the below format of xml.

```
<Floorplan IDValue="123" IDType="FloorplanID" IDRank="primary">
    <FloorplanInfo>info<FloorplanInfo>  
</Floorplan>
<Floorplan IDValue="456" IDType="FloorplanID" IDRank="primary">
    <FloorplanInfo>info<FloorplanInfo>  
</Floorplan>

<unit id = abc1 floorplanid = 123>
    <unitinfo>info</unitinfo>
<unit>
<unit id = abc2 floorplanid = 123>
    <unitinfo>info</unitinfo>
<unit>
<unit id = abc3 floorplanid = 456>
    <unitinfo>info</unitinfo>
 <unit>
 <unit id = abc4 floorplanid = 456>
    <unitinfo>info</unitinfo>
 <unit>
```

Based on the value of the floorplan id's in units i want to map them to the Floorplans and produce an xml of the below format. is this is possible using xslt and what could be the best approach. I am not sure if i have explained in my question in a better way but the example should do it.

```
<Floorplan IDValue="123" IDType="FloorplanID" IDRank="primary">
  <FloorplanInfo>info<FloorplanInfo>    
  <unit id = abc1 floorplanid = 123>
    <unitinfo>info</unitinfo>
   <unit>
  <unit id = abc2 floorplanid = 123>
     <unitinfo>info</unitinfo>
  <unit>
</Floorplan>
<Floorplan IDValue="456" IDType="FloorplanID" IDRank="primary">
        <FloorplanInfo>info<FloorplanInfo>
 <unit id = abc3 floorplanid = 456>
        <unitinfo>info</unitinfo>
 <unit>
 <unit id = abc4 floorplanid = 456>
        <unitinfo>info</unitinfo>
  <unit>    
 </Floorplan>
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: XSLT has built-in **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key)** mechanism for resolving cross-references. You can read an excellent introduction here: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.  FYI: I had to clean up the XML you posted because it was not well formed.

```
    <xsl:key name="myKey" match="unit" use="@floorplanid"/>

    <xsl:template match="Floorplan">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('myKey', @IDValue)" mode="unitMode"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Suppress unit current nodes. -->
    <xsl:template match="unit"/>

    <!-- Use mode to add the new unit nodes.  -->
    <xsl:template match="unit" mode="unitMode">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity template. -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```